# Are these quarters notes or just eighth notes?

Tags: guitar

Are these quarter notes or eighth notes? Which ones are the quarter notes and which are the eighth notes? Are there quarter notes together with 8th notes or are all eighths? Like using the numbers and arrows to tell me which ones are the quarter or eighths?

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a link to the page you found this on or any of the description of this? It sort of looks like they are all 16th notes but that might just be the arm motion and not the strum itself.

Comment: https://tabs.ultimate-guitar.com/tab/print?flats=0&font_size=2&id=2270831&simplified=0&transpose=0

Comment: Baby Can I Hold You Official by Tracy Chapman

Answer (score 3):

Those are sixteenth notes. There are two ways to know:

1. the double beam under each pair; and
2. the counting pattern. The number comes on each beat (i.e. each quarter note), and the "&" comes on the half beat (i.e., each eighth note). The stems between the numbers and "&"s are the sixteenths. They're often counted `1 e & a 2 e & a, etc.`

The strumming pattern assumes that on each sixteenth note, there is a strum motion: down motion on the number and the "&"; up motion on each stem in between. The actual strums occur where indicated by the arrows.

Here is a recreation of the OP image with the common 16th-note counting pattern and up-down hand movement pattern indicated below the rhythm notation.

[image: Up-down 16th note strum pattern and count]

Comment: Impossible to tell whether this was intended in the original source but I'd say it's massive overkill to move your hand that much just to play "ching, ching -ga ching ching; ching ching chacha ching ching". In my opinion it's more plausible the sixteenths were just there to provide a frame so that the correct positioning of the third stroke can been seen exactly, rather than suggesting that "on each sixteenth note, there is a strum motion"

Comment: @JudyN. - do you play rhythm guitar?

Comment: @Tim Yes (Comments must be at least 15 characters in length)

Answer (score 2):

Since they all look the same, with a stem and two beams each, they are definitely sixteenth notes (semi-quavers). That means in one bar there will be 16 of them, all equal. Counting 1-2-3-4 is usually done with 1e&a2e&a3e&a4e&a for each bar of the usual 4 in 4/4 time. Giving the count of 16. Each beat dividing into 4.

The arrows tell which way the strumming goes. But that's pre-determined. With 8 pulses in the bar, 1 down and 1 up. So, every *'number'* and every '*&*' strum down, and every other one will be a return upstrum (fairly obvious!). No arrow means no audible strum, which will still physically take place. It's a rhythm after all, and any rhythm will retain a regular pattern.